# Target routes that end with edit?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

i want know if is possible target routes that end with edit with express.js??

For example, i have normal routes:

```
app.get('/one', controller.one);
app.get('/two', controller.two);
```

I want now if is possible without create one by one, target if something try to go to `/one/edit`, `/two/edit.`

For example.

```
app.get(IF ROUTES END WITH EDIT, function() {
 console.log('edit!');
});
```

Possible?

Comment: You can use a wildcard `app.get('/:something/edit', fn)`

Answer (score 1):

Ideally you should use a wildcard in your route:

```
app.get('/:number/edit', function(request) {
    // ...
});
```

Now the `number` property of the `request.params` object refers to the `:number` segment of the route definition.

Another option is using a regex:

```
app.get(/^\/(one|two)\/edit$/, function(request) {
    // ...
});
```

Now `request.params[0]` refers to the matched string in `(...)` part of the regex.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `$` (ends with)

```
app.get(/.*\/edit$/, function(req, res) {
   console.log('edit!');
});
```